# NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification best way to update the UI?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsnotificationcenter

In my code i have an `mainManagedObjectContext` and a `backgroundManagedObjectContext` and its working great.

I moved all my save code to the `backgroundManagedObjectContext` and merging the differences between the contexts via `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`.

Now I want to update my UI after `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`. What is the best approach beside of a `NSFetchedResultController` to do this?

The changes in my object is visible via the debugger and I could use KVO for this, but IMHO it's a terrible idea. In my abstraction i got a Model to handle the database calls and it would be great when my Model also handling changes after merging the context.

What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: Using NSFetchedResultController with delegate methods is the best way.

Comment: Actually for a non-uitableview based view a fetched results container is a bit heavy. I would just update on the main thread using NSNotification stemming from your NSManagedObjectDidSaveNotification.

Comment: @GuybrushThreepwood tried this it ended in a EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS are you on the right thread?

Comment: Yep agree Jim - check the threading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out, for table and collection views, the best bet is `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`.

Another mechanism is to register for this (or your custom) notification `NSNotificationCenter`, e.g. for the original notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
       addObserver:self 
          selector:@selector(updateUI:) 
              name:NSManagedObjectContextDidChangeNotification 
            object:nil];
```

Best do this in `viewDidAppear`. Don't forget to remove the observer in `viewWillDisappear`. Note that following the comment I am using the change notification rather than the save notification.

In your non-table view controllers you should isolate the UI setup, similar to the boilerplate code for the fetched results controller delegate, which implements a method like `configureCell:atIndexPath:`. You can then simply call this setup routine when you get the notification without duplicating any code.

Comment: It may be better to observe `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` instead. You care about when objects change, not when they save, and the notification appears to be batched sanely to happen during `processPendingChanges`. You also know which properties changed that way, which can be useful for selectively updating the UI, where that information would already be destroyed post-save.